# Delete number from contacts

Tags: android, contacts

The following code lets me display duplicate contacts.
And when I try to delete, it deletes the duplicated number as well as the original number.
I want it to delete only the duplicated number present in the listview.

Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> dupesRemoved = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] newList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        String order = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
        Cursor curLog =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,order);
        Cursor cursor = null;

        if(curLog != null) {
            while(curLog.moveToNext()) {
                String str = curLog.getString(curLog.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                //contactid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
                listItems.add(str);
            }
        }
        dupesRemoved = findDuplicates(listItems);
        String listString = dupesRemoved.toString();
        listString = listString.substring(1,listString.length()-1);
        newList = listString.split(", ");
        //Arrays.sort(newList);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    public void deleteDupes(View view) {
        String[] info = new String[2];

        for (String s : newList) {
          info = (getContactInfo(s));

          updateContact(info[0],this,info[1]);

        listView.invalidateViews();
        }
    }




        public void updateContact(String contactId, Activity act, String type){

            /* ASSERT: @contactId alreay has a work phone number */
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            String selectPhone = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=?";
            String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId,type /*String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)*/};

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs).build());
        try {
            act.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> findDuplicates(List<String> listContainingDuplicates) {

        final Set<String> setToReturn = new HashSet<String>();
        final Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String yourInt : listContainingDuplicates) {
            if (!set1.add(yourInt)) {
                setToReturn.add(yourInt);
            }
        }
        return setToReturn;
    }
    private String[] getContactInfo(String number)
    {
        String[] contactInfo = new String[2];

        ContentResolver context = getContentResolver();

        /// number is the phone number
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(number));

        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE };

        Cursor cur = context.query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try
        {
            if (cur.moveToFirst())
            {
                contactInfo[0] = cur.getString(0);
                contactInfo[1] = cur.getString(2);
                return contactInfo;


            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        return contactInfo;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your select statement doesn't seem to differentiate between duplicates from what I can tell. Then again, this is a lot of code and I'm unsure what is relevant.

Comment: the findDuplicate method does find the duplicates :P

Comment: Yes, but does the delete method select differentiate between the duplicate and the original or does it just remove both as they are the same and will be found by the same searches? I'm not saying this is the problem but it's probably something in this direction.

Comment: ah well yes! And now this code actually deletes the duplicated number. The problem is what u said here....it deletes both the entries ONLY when their fields are also same...otherwise it deletes only the duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Use hashmap instead of arraylist to store items in key value pair as duplicate keys are not allowed in a map.

Answer (score 0):

Java code for delete contact:

```
public static boolean deleteContact(Context ctx, String phone, String name) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                }

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: this deletes the entire contact...i want to delete only the duplicate and not both the duplicate and the orginal